# Is an output layer with 2 units and softmax better than one with 1 unit and sigmoid for binary classification using LSTM?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm, rnn

I am using an LSTM for binary classification and initially tried a model with 1 unit in the output(Dense) layer with sigmoid as the activation function. However, it didn't perform well and I saw a few notebooks where they used 2 units in the output layer(the layer immediately after the LSTM) with softmax as the activation function. Is there any advantage to using 2 output layers and using softmax instead of a single unit and sigmoid(For the purpose of binary classification)? I am using binary_crossentropy as the loss function

Comment: I haven't been able to find any studies comparing the methods though I suspect the former method may be more mathematically efficient in passing gradients for weight updates.